# how to configure mysql 5.5.35 with hive 0.12

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to configure MySQL with Hive 0.12 here is what I did -

I installed

MySQL - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
mysql-connector-java-5.1.30 and copied the jar file in $HIVE_HOME/lib
Installed HIVE 0.12

Here is the hive-site.xml entries

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
        <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hiveuser</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>hivepassword</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

When I go into the hive shell and try to create a table it gives me the following error -

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Please advise.

Comment: Hive now records the schema version in the metastore database and verifies that the metastore schema version is compatible with Hive binaries that are going to accesss the metastore. Note that the Hive properties to implicitly create or alter the existing schema are disabled by default. Hive will not attempt to change the metastore schema implicitly. When you execute a Hive query against an old schema, it will fail to access the metastore.

Comment: To suppress the schema check and allow the metastore to implicitly modify the schema, you need to set a configuration property hive.metastore.schema.verification to false in hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive now records the schema version in the metastore database and verifies that the metastore schema version is compatible with Hive binaries that are going to accesss the metastore. Note that the Hive properties to implicitly create or alter the existing schema are disabled by default. Hive will not attempt to change the metastore schema implicitly. When you execute a Hive query against an old schema, it will fail to access the metastore.

To suppress the schema check and allow the metastore to implicitly modify the schema, you need to set a configuration property hive.metastore.schema.verification to false in hive-site.xml.

Got it resolved now here is what I did -

```
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```

Resolved.

To follow the steps please visit my blog at [MySQL with Hive](http://rajnishbigdata.wordpress.com/mysql-with-hive/)

Answer (score 0):

can you also please add below properties and check

```
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
 <value>true</value>`enter code here`
</property>
```

also check if  you MySQL service is running.

```
service mysqld status
```

should show running...

Comment: I got it resolved yesterday itself I just added hive.metastore.schema.verification to false in hive-site.xml and it worked. Thanks for your inputs though.